# Action when pressing return key on keyboard (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, ibaction

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField 
{
    [self checkRun:nil];
    return YES;
}
```

I'm trying to complete the `IBAction` `checkRun` when the return key is pressed, by using the above code, but it doesn't seem to be working. Where am I going wrong? I thought maybe it's because I'm not directly referencing the textfield that I'm typing in, but I can't work out where I'd need to put the name of that textfield.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you set the text field's `delegate`? Do you know if the above method is being called or not?

Comment: Oh my, no I hadn't! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *textField;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.textField.delegate = self;
}
```

Comment: This is right, thanks, but for reference, I got away with just dragging 'delegate' to the view controller in IB. Probably not good practice, but it worked.

Comment: Actually, dragging the delegate to the view controller in IB is the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

This UITextfield subclass enables you to set a condition for the text and dynamically change the UIReturnKey:
https://github.com/codeinteractiveapps/OBReturnKeyTextField